# How to remove js using theme, which was added by plugin in WordPress site?

Tags: javascript

I have my WordPress site. It has one plugin which adds a JavaScript which I don't want to use. I want to remove it from my site using theme.

Tried multiple solutions like added hook in function file to dequeue the script but doesn't work for me.

Comment: You can refer to the wp_dequeue_script  function for it. Check out this one - [wp_dequeue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_script/)

Comment: It might help if you could show the code you are using to dequeue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code with the required changes in the theme's function file.

Refer to the documentation for more info

- [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_enqueue_scripts/)
- [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/)
- [wp_deregister_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/)

```
  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_thrive_appr_main_script' );
  function remove_thrive_appr_main_script() {
      wp_deregister_script( 'handle-of-style' );
  }
```

Note - 'handle-of-style' = handle of style (You have to replace it with your own one)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Where to put this one? In function file of the theme or in header file.

Comment: Add this one to your theme's function file.

Comment: It is working one. Thank you so much Ashok :)